# What prompts breathe reminders on an Apple Watch?

Tags: notifications, apple-watch

WatchOS 3 included a breathe app that gives occasional reminders to "take a minute to breathe".

What prompts these reminders? Does it monitor your heart rate to know when you're stressed, or does it remind you at preset times?

[image: Apple reminding us to breathe some good old O²]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, breathe reminders are set to display every 5 hours. [According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206999), you can adjust or disable the reminders by doing the following.

> 1. Open the Apple Watch app on your iPhone and tap the My Watch tab.
> 2. Tap Breathe > Breathe Reminders.
> 3. Choose how often you get reminders.

Comment: I want to get reminders and have set mine to remind me 4 times per day but iWatch 3 doesn’t prompt at all. It only randomly prompts me once a week.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the reminders to breathe are connected to actual respiration measurements. Every time I get the alert I become aware that I had been holding my breathe. .. Or maybe just I hold my breathe a lot and only become cognizant, when my alert goes off.